# Docker: Use PHP in container with locally installed apache

Tags: php, docker

I have apache and PHP7 installed in my machine. I want to use apache with a PHP5 installed in a docker container, how can I tell apache to use the PHP5 of container instead of the PHP7 locally installed ?

Comment: create docker file which has php5. your docker config have no concern what is being installed in ur system

Comment: How can I link my apache with that PHP5 docker file?

Comment: http://linuxplayer.org/2011/05/intall-multiple-version-of-php-on-one-server
install php5 in docker and set configuration in appache.conf

Comment: mount php5 with host and expose php 9000 from docker